# Can't Type in <input> tags

Tags: html, css, position

I'm currently trying to create a form on my website's front page. However, Im having issues being able to type within the input boxes. In absolute positioning, the cursor doesn't show up. When I change the positioning from absolute to relative, I no longer have this issue. Unfortunately, when I do this, it moves all my other elements down. Is there a way around this so the tag doesn't move my other elements down, along with being able to type into this input boxes?

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <div id="head_login">
            Login
            <div id="arrow-down"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="head_break"></div>
    <div class="content_splash">
        <form>
        **<input type="text" id="firstname" /></form>**
        <div id="vertical_one"></div>
        <div id="vertical_two"></div>
        <p id="OR"> OR </p>
        <div id="facebook_login"><img src="{% static 'home/facebook_login.gif' %}" /></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content_break"></div>
    <div class="content_description">
    <h2> What is the Title? </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="content_description_break"></div>
    <div class="content_howitworks">
    <h2> How it Works.</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="footer_break"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
content_splash{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.content_splash input{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
.content_splash #firstname{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 170px;
    height: 25px;
}
.content_splash #vertical_one{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px; 
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 310px;
    margin-top: 298px;
    background: black;
}
.content_splash #vertical_two{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px; 
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 310px;
    margin-top: 380px;
    background: black;
}
.content_splash #OR{
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 346px;
    padding-left:300px;
    color: black;
}
.content_splash #facebook_login{
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 350px;
    padding-left: 350px;

}
#content_break {
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 1px;
    background: black;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(#e2e3e4), to(#e2e3e4), color-stop(50%, black));  
}
.content_description{
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 400px;
}
.content_description h2{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: #a2caf6;
}
#content_description_break {
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 1px;
    background: black;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(#e2e3e4), to(#e2e3e4), color-stop(50%, black));  
}
.content_howitworks{
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 400px;
}
.content_howitworks h2{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: #a2caf6;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add a z-index to the input.

```
.content_splash #firstname{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 170px;
    height: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/v9jPB/1/)

**EDIT**

As by request of @gaitat, I will explain why this works.

Assume the following HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    I am the parent.

    <div class="child red">I am the red child.</div>

    <div class="child blue">I am the blue child.</div>

    <div class="child green">I am the green child.</div>
</div>
```

Now, also assume the following css:

```
.parent
{
    position: relative;
}

.child
{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
}

.red
{
    background-color: red;
}

.blue
{
    background-color: blue;
}

.green
{
    background-color: green;
}
```

[See the JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cLgdp4nj/)

As you can see, in the DOM, the green child is the last child of parent, thus it's rendered last. The last rendered element, assuming an absolute position and no `z-index` is used, will be rendered on top.

Now, when we add a z-index to the red child:

```
.red
{
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

You will see that the red child will be rendered on top, because his z-index is higher than the other children, who have a z-index of 0 (default). [See the JSFiddle here showing this.](http://jsfiddle.net/cLgdp4nj/1/)

Do keep in mind that this only works with **siblings sharing the same direct parent**, otherwise it will not.

Comment: Can you explain why this is happening ?